# Расположить по центру по вертикали текст в блоке

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Есть дизайн.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно расположить текст по центру слайда.
Вот HTML

```
<div class="promo_slider">
    <div class="promo_slider_slide">
        <h1>Строительство домов и социальных зданий.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et his fuisset vulputate. At pro nostro argumentum, id mei adipisci referrentur<br /> delicatissimi, iisque repudiandae an his. Mel veritus pericula an, mea inimicus neglegentur ei.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Высота слайда должна быть не меньше высоты окна браузера. Нужно чтобы работало в Firefox тоже. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 .promo_slider {
   background-color: gray;
   height: 50vh;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
 .promo_slider_slide {
   display: flex;
   color: #fff;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
 .promo_slider_slide > p {
   margin-top: 100px;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="promo_slider">
    <div class="promo_slider_slide">
        <h1>Строительство домов и социальных зданий.</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et his fuisset vulputate. At pro nostro argumentum, id mei adipisci referrentur<br /> delicatissimi, iisque repudiandae an his. Mel veritus pericula an, mea inimicus neglegentur ei.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало.

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте комментариев, как это работает, и какая часть вашего решения важна для ответа на вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```
.promo_slider_slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Это самый безгеморройный способ.

Comment: Мне не только по горизонтали но и по вертикали нужно

Comment: Исправил ответ.